# I can't run my flutter project after I changed the Dart SDK to an older version on android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I downloaded a Udemy course from torrent and got the videos and all the resources. In the resources there was a copied git repository which consisted the project files for that flutter project. I created a project by cloning from that repository in android studio. Apparently, the created that project using an older Dart SDK version (2.12.0) but I was using 3.2.0 so I downloaded an older stable windows version of Dart SDK (2.12.0) because it was asking me to get that version due to some Null-safety feature to run. So I successfully downloaded the SDK version as ZIP and placed it in the SDK folder with the SDK which I was already using and gave it's path to android studio using SDK manager. But after changing switching the version it won't let me run the project or even the button of "Get Dependencies" is not showing. The Run button is greyed out and also the devices are not showing on which I can run the project. I even updated the SDK version in the pubspec.yaml file
[Screenshot of the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvSD8.png)

I tried using an older version of Dart SDK in which the project was made by the developer but after setting up the SDK successfully, I don't know what went or or what I am missing because the run button is greyed out and I cant run the project.

Comment: You are trying run old dart version on updated framework might not work. You need to update the project and their packages. If you don't want to do that, install older version of flutter framework sdk instead of only dart sdk. https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=windows